# Select dropdown menu doesn't work as expected and doesn't deselect all

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to do simple dropdown menu with multiple selection options. Everything seems to work fine except when I click on first option, `all` in my case, it should deselect all other but it doesn't.

Also, if selected options are more than 3 I'm trying to show `4 select(s)`, `5 select(s)`, etc which also doesn't work.

Code I have so far and working demo

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker();
        $('.selectStatuses').on('change', function() {
            if ($('option[value="all"]', this).is(':selected') && $(this).val().length > 1) {
                $('option[value="all"]', this).prop('selected', false);
                $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
            }
            var selected = $(this).val();
            if (selected.length > 3) {
                $(this).selectpicker('setStyle', 'selected-count', 'btn-danger');
                $(this).selectpicker('setTitle', selected.length + ' select(s)');
            } else {
                $(this).selectpicker('setStyle', 'selected-count', 'btn-default');
                $(this).selectpicker('setTitle', 'Select');
            }
        });
    });
```

```css
.select {
  /* for demo only */
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/css/bootstrap-select.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-select@1.13.14/dist/js/bootstrap-select.min.js"></script>
<div class="select">
  <select class="input-fields selectStatuses" name="status[]" multiple>
      <option value="all" selected>All statuses</option>
      <option value="status_1">Status 1</option>
      <option value="status_2">Status 2</option>
      <option value="status_3">Status 3</option>
      <option value="status_4">Status 4</option>
      <option value="status_5">Status 5</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

JSFiddle also if need: https://jsfiddle.net/752kcubr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite tricky, first of all your on change is always triggering twice, avoid that by using the:

```
e.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

Other than that it's quite tricky, since `"$(this).val();"` is giving the same result if we select the first option then the second, or the second option and then the first, and we need them to do different results. We can get by that with setting a local variable to keep track what you have clicked before. Here's one solution, you can rename and use bool values instead but the point stands and the code is working for your example:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker();
    let oldValue = $('option[value="all"]').val();
    $('.selectStatuses').on('change', function(e) {
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            
if ($('option[value="all"]', this).is(':selected') && oldValue == "all") {
            $('option[value="all"]', this).prop('selected', false);
            $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
            oldValue = "";
        } else if ($('option[value="all"]', this).is(':selected')){
            $('option[value="status_1"]', this).prop('selected', false);
            $('option[value="status_2"]', this).prop('selected', false);
            $('option[value="status_3"]', this).prop('selected', false);
            $('option[value="status_4"]', this).prop('selected', false);
            $('option[value="status_5"]', this).prop('selected', false);
            $('.selectStatuses').selectpicker('refresh');
            // loop over and set all other options to false here instead of setting them manually

             oldValue = "all";
        }

        var selected = $(this).val();
        if (selected.length > 3) {
            $(this).selectpicker('setStyle', 'selected-count', 'btn-danger');
            $(this).selectpicker('setTitle', selected.length + ' select(s)');
        } else {
            $(this).selectpicker('setStyle', 'selected-count', 'btn-default');
            $(this).selectpicker('setTitle', 'Select');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer and sorry for the late response. The code doesn't work as expected. If I click on all 5 choices and then click on `All statuses` it deselects only the first two but the remaining `status 3`, `Status 4` and `Status 5` are still selected.

Comment: Hi,

Just add the rest of the options in the second else if statement

 $('option[value="status_1"]', this).prop('selected', false);
 $('option[value="status_2"]', this).prop('selected', false);
 $('option[value="status_3"]', this).prop('selected', false);
 $('option[value="status_4"]', this).prop('selected', false);
 $('option[value="status_5"]', this).prop('selected', false);

But you should ideally make a loop there instead, i made a comment in the code.

Comment: Can you show me an example how to do this loop. Am not very familiar with JS. Thanks!

Comment: here is a version that works with all options including new ones to be added https://jsfiddle.net/ogstnd6q/12/